# (AMDGPU-PRO) Secondary Screens VGA W/DVI doesn't work but HDMI does

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics, vga, dvi

So I have R9 380 fresh install of Ubuntu Mate.
Install the AMDGPU Pro drivers.  Op success

Issue:
Secondary Monitor with VGA w/DVI adaptor is detected but gets no signal.

Trouble Shoot: Swapped it out w/32in HDTV and the TV worked with HDMI

Hypnosis: 
Some kind of analog issue with AMD.  The secondary monitor with vga w/dvi adaptor works fine on Windows and default amdgpu drivers.

Aspirations: 
Someone awesome provides a software solution so I do not have to buy a new secondary non-vga 19" monitor.

Comment: DVI-D-1 connected 1280x960+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
I think the problem is that the DVI-I port is being read as a DVI-D port.

Answer (score 1):

On my Dell M6700 laptop containing Heathrow XT Radeon HD 7870M with amdgpu-pro 17.10-446706 installed (on kde neon), the external display wasn't being recognised either.

Swapped the VGA cable for a DisplayPort one, problem solved.

Comment: I confirm: this solution works. VGA to DisplayPort is 15€ though, not the cheapest but the easiest

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not allowed to comment, I'm having the same issue. Got a  new (to me) tv as a secondary monitor to replace my ancient 4:3 lcd, plugged it in via vga and it won't let me set a 16:9 resolution. Installed the AMDGPU PRO drivers, rebooted and now it doesn't even see the secondary screen as connected. Will uninstall AMDGPU Pro drivers for the time being.

Comment: I just have issue with VGA w/DVI adapters.  I think its the DVI-I port being read as DVI-D which is probably ignoring the analog .